# how to escape wild character _ underscore in LIKE SOQL Clause

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I have this query
`Select Id, Email, ContactId, Username  from User where Username Like '\_%'`
works perfectly with Devloper console and give me users whose **username starts with _**

I am using this code in apex, but there its not giving the desired result.

**From salesforce docs**

> The LIKE operator in SOQL and SOSL supports escaping of special characters % or _. 
>   Don’t use the backslash character in a search except to escape a special character.

PS : I have tried escaping double backslash `\\_` , four backslash `\\\\_`, `[_]` . None worked. and not escaping also.

Comment: Have you tried NOT escaping it?

Comment: yes, Then it gives all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am adding answer here using normal SOQL also

**Working**

```
 String strLike = '\\_%';
    system.debug([Select Id, Email, ContactId, Username  from User where Username  Like :strLike ]);
```

**as well using dynamic query**

```
List<User> users = (List<User>)Database.query('Select Id, Email, ContactId, Username  from User where Username Like \'\\_%\'');
```

Answer (score 6):

In my tests, a double backslash escape has provided the desired results:

```java
List<User> users = (List<User>)Database.query('Select Id, Email, ContactId, Username  from User where Username Like \'\\_%\'');
```

Comment: How about static SOQL?

Comment: This worked. But I am wondering, how n why.
same using normal soql not working. wt does Database.query method made the difference.

Comment: what about this `[Select Id, Email, ContactId, Username  from User where (Email IN: setEmailIds OR ContactId IN: lstNewContact) AND (NOT Username Like '\_%')]`